# View being shown as merged with View beneath

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have two Views that are positioned on top of each other. The first stays in position and is visible at all times. The second has its visibility toggled by the user and slides in (and out) (using an animation) from (and to) the right of the screen. The problem is that the two Views when showing together, get merged such that you can see bits of the first View beneath the second View. Is there a property I can set on the second View such that it covers the first View totally out of sight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using ViewSwitcher?http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html

Comment: Didn't know it existed! (Thanks.) Can it be used such that one View stays in place and a second View slides in and out on top of it?

Comment: When the views are not visible the views continues to exist, you can update things on them - they are not destroyed, you can add animations to switch between the two to have the sliding effect you describe.

Comment: Thanks. Will try it out. Will the problem still not remain though that whilst the second is sliding over the first, the user can see bits of the first through the second? Any solutions for that, i.e. how to display a second View on top of a first such it obscures the first totally out of sight?

Comment: Try it and let us know if the problem still exists. I have not seen the problem you describe when using ViewSwitcher

Comment: Ok. Will try it out and let you know how I get on. Thanks again.

Comment: Got ViewSwitcher to work. Although it didn't solve the initial problem of sliding in (and out) a second View on top of a first (such that the first is kept fixed in place and totally obscured behind the second View as the second View slides in),  I ended up using a slide in and slide out animation with the ViewSwitcher such that the first View slides out as the second View slides in and vice and versa. Any answers to the initial problem will be greatly appreciated!